# Limit of a bounded integral

Tags: real-analysis

I need to prove that $$\int_{-1}^1\frac{x^2}{1+x^{2n}}dx\leq 2/3\text{ for all }n\in\mathbb{N}\text{.}$$ Not sure how to begin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x^{2n} \geq 0$, $x^2 \geq 0$, so $\frac{x^2}{1+x^{2n}} \leq \frac{x^2}{1+0} = x^2$.

What is $\int_{-1}^1 x^2$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Just that $$\frac{1}{1+x^{2n}}\leq 1$$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is obtained easily by

$$\frac{x^2}{1+x^{2n}}\le x^2$$
but there's an other way: the sequence $\left(\frac{x^2}{1+x^{2n}}\right)_n$ is increasing so by the monotonic convergence theorem we have
$$\int_{-1}^1\frac{x^2}{1+x^{2n}}dx\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-1}^1\frac{x^2}{1+x^{2n}}dx=\int_{-1}^1\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^2}{1+x^{2n}}dx=\int_{-1}^1x^2dx=\frac23$$

Answer (score 0):

Show that $\int\limits_{0}^{1}\dfrac{x^2}{1+x^{2n}} \leq \int\limits_{0}^{1}\dfrac{x^2}{1+x^{2}}$ and then you shall have your inequality